# merge dictionaries in Ansible that have the same keys

Tags: python, dictionary, ansible

once again I'm trying to accomplish something with Ansible.

I built a custom dict with variables for each server that looks like this.

```yaml
- name: Create and Add items to server_list
  set_fact: 
    server_list: "{{ server_list | default({}) | combine ({ item.key : item.value }) }}"
  with_items:
    - { 'key': 'Servername' , 'value': "{{ ansible_hostname }}"}
    - { 'key': 'IP-Adresse' , 'value': "{{ ansible_default_ipv4.address }}"}
    - { 'key': 'OS' , 'value': "{{ ansible_os_family }} {{ ansible_distribution_major_version }}"}
    - { 'key': 'Plattform' , 'value': "{{ ansible_system }}"}

- name: DEBUG server_list
  debug:
    var=server_list
```

That's working. But now ansible outputs this for every server like this:

```json
ok: [XXX] => {
    "server_list": {
        "IP-Adresse": "x.x.x.x",
        "OS": "Debian 11",
        "Plattform": "Linux",
        "Servername": "XXX"
    }
}
ok: [YYY] => {
    "server_list": {
        "IP-Adresse": "x.x.x.y",
        "OS": "Debian 11",
        "Plattform": "Linux",
        "Servername": "YYY"
    }
}

...
```

What I want to have now is a complete and "global" dict with every server. I think that would look like this.
Example of what I want as output (here named as `server_list_dict`):

```json
{
    "server_list_dict": {
        "0": {
            "Servername": "XXX",
            "IP-Adresse": "x.x.x.x",
            "OS": "Debian 11",
            "Plattform": "Linux"
        },
        "1": {
            "Servername": "YYY",
            "IP-Adresse": "x.x.x.y",
            "OS": "Debian 11",
            "Plattform": "Linux"
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Only for clarification for what I want to achieve**

What I want to do later is create a html table that should output something like this.
Example html that I want to create:

```html
<table style="width:50%">
    <!-- table header -->
    <tr>
        <th>Servername</th>
        <th>IP</th>
        <th>OS</th>
        <th>Platform</th>
    </tr>  
    <!-- table rows -->
    <tr>
        <td>Hostname1</td>
        <td>X.X.X.X</td>
        <td>Debian</td>
        <td>Linux</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Hostname2</td>
        <td>X.X.X.Y</td>
        <td>Debian</td>
        <td>Linux</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I already have a template to use.
This will go through my "global" dict with every server and use all of the keys and values that are in there. (hopefully, couldnt test it, because idk how to merge my dicts)

```
<table style="width:100%">
  <!-- table header -->
  {% if server_list_dict %}
  <tr>
     {% for key in server_list_dict[0] %}
     <th> {{ key }} </th>
     {% endfor %}
  </tr>
  {% endif %}

  <!-- table rows -->
  {% for dict_item in server_list_dict %}
  <tr>
     {% for value in dict_item.values() %}
     <td> {{ value }} </td>
     {% endfor %}
  </tr>
  {% endfor %}
</table>
```

Does anybody know how to merge dicts with the same keys in a complete dict? I couldn't find anything useful. Thanks everyone in advance!

Comment: server_dict has a different content following your host...so could you precise what you want..its not clear .. about your template where do you want the result on each host..?

Comment: @Frenchy so the html result (with the use of the j2 template there), should only be on the deployment host (could do that with delegate_to), but actually i dont care if its done on every host. The thing is, that i have mutliple dicts now (each for every server because of the set_fact) and i want to combine all of them in one global dict (like the example i wrote with `server_list_dict` to show where i want to go). Then with the use of the global dict and the for loop in the j2 template, I want to have my html structured as shown in the html example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extract the list of the variables *server_list*

```yaml
server_lsts: "{{ ansible_play_hosts|
                 map('extract', hostvars, 'server_list')|list }}"
```

gives

```yaml
server_lsts:
  - IP-Adresse: x.x.x.x
    OS: Debian 11
    Plattform: Linux
    Servername: XXX
  - IP-Adresse: x.x.x.y
    OS: Debian 11
    Plattform: Linux
    Servername: YYY
```

and create the dictionary

```yaml
server_dict: "{{ dict(ansible_play_hosts|zip(server_lsts)) }}"
```

gives

```yaml
server_dict:
  XXX:
    IP-Adresse: x.x.x.x
    OS: Debian 11
    Plattform: Linux
    Servername: XXX
  YYY:
    IP-Adresse: x.x.x.y
    OS: Debian 11
    Plattform: Linux
    Servername: YYY
```

---

- Example of a complete playbook

```yaml
- hosts: all
  vars:
    server_lsts: "{{ ansible_play_hosts|
                     map('extract', hostvars, 'server_list')|list }}"
    server_dict: "{{ dict(ansible_play_hosts|zip(server_lsts)) }}"
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: server_dict
      run_once: true
```

- Put the declaration of the dictionary into the *group_vars*. For example

```yaml
shell> cat group_vars/all.yml
server_list:
  Servername: "{{ ansible_hostname }}"
  IP-Adresses: "{{ ansible_all_ipv4_addresses }}"
  OS: "{{ ansible_os_family }} {{ ansible_distribution_major_version }}"
  Plattform: "{{ ansible_system }}"
```

The playbook

```yaml
- hosts: test_11:test_12
  vars:
    server_lsts: "{{ ansible_play_hosts|
                     map('extract', hostvars, 'server_list')|list }}"
    server_dict: "{{ dict(ansible_play_hosts|zip(server_lsts)) }}"
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: server_dict
      run_once: true
```

gives

```yaml
server_dict:
  test_11:
    IP-Adresses:
      - 10.1.0.61
    OS: FreeBSD 13
    Plattform: FreeBSD
    Servername: test_11
  test_12:
    IP-Adresses:
      - 10.1.0.62
    OS: FreeBSD 13
    Plattform: FreeBSD
    Servername: test_12
```

- If you want to index the dictionaries create the sequence. For example

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: test_11:test_12
  vars:
    server_lsts: "{{ ansible_play_hosts|
                     map('extract', hostvars, 'server_list')|list }}"
    params: "start=0 count={{ ansible_play_hosts|length }}"
    server_dict: "{{ dict(q('sequence', params)|zip(server_lsts)) }}"
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: server_dict
      run_once: true
```

gives

```yaml
server_dict:
  '0':
    IP-Adresses:
      - 10.1.0.61
    OS: FreeBSD 13
    Plattform: FreeBSD
    Servername: test_11
  '1':
    IP-Adresses:
      - 10.1.0.62
    OS: FreeBSD 13
    Plattform: FreeBSD
    Servername: test_12
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you, you're awesome. That definitely looks like what I wanted. I'm currently testing everything :)

Answer (score 2):

you could directly use jinja to create your var as expected:

```
  tasks:
    - name: Create and Add items to server_list
      set_fact: 
        server_list: >- 
              {%- set result = {} -%}
              {%- for server in ansible_play_hosts -%}
              {%- set idx = loop.index0 -%}
              {%- set name = hostvars[server].ansible_hostname -%}
              {%- set ip = hostvars[server].ansible_default_ipv4.address -%}
              {%- set os = hostvars[server].ansible_os_family -%}
              {%- set pf = hostvars[server].ansible_system -%}
              {%- set _= result.update({idx: {"Servername": name, "IP": ip, "OS": os, "Platform": pf} }) -%}
              {%- endfor -%}
              {{ result }}
      
    - debug:
        msg: "{{server_list}}"
```

Answer (score 1):

> *... Ansible outputs this for every server ...  I have mutliple dicts now (each for every server because of the `set_fact`) ...*

This is since [`gather_facts` module – Gathers facts about remote hosts](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/gather_facts_module.html) and [`set_fact` module – Set host variable(s) and fact(s)](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/set_fact_module.html) are running distributed on the Remote Node(s) and the expected behavior.

> *What I want to have now is a complete and "global" dict with every server.*

I understand your question that you like to [delegate facts](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_delegation.html#delegating-facts) first to one of the hosts, the Control Node (Deployment Host or localhost) where you can than create your file or use your template for further distribution. There, all the information would be aggregated in one data structure (dictionary) already.

An other approach might be to use [caching facts](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_vars_facts.html#caching-facts) via [cache plugins](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/cache.html#enabling-fact-cache-plugins).

**Documentation**

- [Delegating facts](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_delegation.html#delegating-facts)